# How do I make pandoc add a package to my header when transpiling Markdown to LATeX?

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I have a Markdown file that I want to compile to LaTeX. I want to put `\usepackage{tikz}` in the header. Here's what I tried:

```
$ cat test.md | pandoc -s -f markdown -t latex -H \usepackage{tikz} > test.tex
File usepackage{tikz} not found in resource path
```

Then I removed the `-H` flag and made a YAML header for my Markdown.

```yaml
---
title: My title
author: My name
header-includes:
  - '`\usepackage{tikz}`{=latex}'
---
```

It yields

> File tikz not found in resource path.

I'm using Tectonic so I don't have TikZ installed locally. I just want to add a string of text to my header, so I guess I must be on the wrong path if `pandoc` expects to find software in some path.

How do I make `pandoc` add a package to my header?

Comment: I know only a little about Tectonic; but as far as I know, it downloads packages from CTAN? And after compilation, it removes them? Anyway, your error message is saying that it is looking for file "tikz"; but at least you have to look for file "tikz.sty"; which contains (hopefully all) definitions. This looks like `tectonic` specific issue. About headers, I am not entirely sure what you mean while converting to `latex` with `pandoc`; but among other things you can modify default latex template (that might be the most straightforward way), save it and call in it `template` variable.

Comment: Last line should be  `<space><space>-<space>\usepackage{tikz}` and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [comment of Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560709/how-do-i-make-pandoc-add-a-package-to-my-header-when-transpiling-markdown-to-lat#comment1414192_560709) did the trick.

Instead of:

```
  - '`\usepackage{tikz}`{=latex}'
```

I had to use

```
  - \usepackage{tikz}
```

and make sure that pandoc is called without `-H \usepackage{tikz}`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
> pandoc --standalone \
  -H packages.tex \
  -f markdown \
  -t latex -o book.pdf \
  mymarkdownfile.md
```

Note the `-H packages.tex`. That file includes all the packages I want in the header, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{...}
...
```